# cannot use a (type [10]string) as type []string in argument to strings.Join

Tags: go

i am trying to pass a array with fix size into a string.join function. how can i pass array with define index into string.join function

program

```
package main

import(
"fmt"
"strings"
)

func main() {

    var a [10]string
    fmt.Println("emp:", a)
    a[2] = "hello"
    a[4] = "member of"
    a[8] = "google"
    str2 := strings.Join(a, " ")
    fmt.Println(str2)
   
}
```

output

```
cannot use a (type [10]string) as type []string in argument to strings.Join
```

do i need to convet it in []string or any other solution is posible

Comment: str2 := strings.Join(a[:], " ")

Comment: Join take a slice. Convert your array to a slice as `[:]`

Answer (score 6):

`strings.Join` expects the argument to be slice. So, you need to convert the string array to slice like below

```
...
str2 := strings.Join(a[:], " ")
...
```